# Trying to convert curl to ansible play

Tags: ansible

I am trying to convert the following curl to ansible play using uri module:
`curl -u user:password -X PUT "http://xxxxxxxxrest/api/1.0/projects/project/repos/my-repo/permissions/groups?permission=REPO_WRITE&name=TestGroup"`

Can someone advise how to add the values in the playbook? The below does not work. ERROR: The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method

```
  - name: Add Permission to Group
    uri:
      url: http://xxxxxxxxrest/api/1.0/projects/project/repos/myrepo/permissions/groups
      method: PUT
      user: user
      password: password
      body: "permission={REPO_WRITE}"
      body: "name={TestGroup}"
      force_basic_auth: yes
      status_code: 200
```

Comment: Which format is expected by the rest service in the body, json?

Comment: Your curl URL uses `my-repo`, while your Ansible URL has `myrepo` - not sure whether that is an issue or just inconsistent dummy data... Doesn't look right, though.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  body: "permission={REPO_WRITE}"
>  body: "name={TestGroup}"
> ```

I don't have any idea why you moved those to the body when they're not in the body of your `curl`; they're query parameters in your `curl`, as they should be in your `uri:` invocation, too:

```
- uri:
    url: http://xx.../groups?permission=REPO_WRITE&name=TestGroup
```

Having said that, watch out for the non-idempotent behavior (unless you have a `when:` elsewhere that guards this `uri:`) because ansible doesn't know what the uri *does* and thus can't make any claims about whether that uri needs to take place or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matthew! Yes, I got mixed up. I am new to this..It is working now.